# How to get the polygon defining a road when I have the way's `osm_id`?

Tags: openstreetmap

I have the `osm_id` of various roads defined in OpenStreetMap and I am trying to get the polygon defining the road. How might I do this, preferably in JavaScript and preferably without downloading data from OSM to my own server. I am new the whole GIS ecosystem so I apologise if my question does not make sense because I misunderstood something.

What I intent to do is to highlight certain roads on my map and for that I thought of adding a new layer (I am using Mapbox.js) which would contain a coloured polygon over the road I'm trying to highlight.

Comment: What exactly you want to do? Have you tried the API? http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6 or http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

Comment: Please give us some feedback. The S.E. is not just to answer you, but to answer all. The people must know what answer is solving this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OSM's regular [API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6) for fetching the OSM way via its ID. Example: https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/136322077/full

The `/full` is important for fetching all of its *nodes*, too. The nodes define the geometry of the way. The order of the nodes is defined by the `<nd ref>` elements of the way. See [OSM XML](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) for more information.

Also read about [when *not* to use this API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#When_NOT_to_use_the_API) and the [API usage policy](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_usage_policy). Since this is the *editing* API it is not meant for bulk queries.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

try this:

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/lookup?osm_ids=R146656,W104393803,N240109189

You must try to do a `GET` in your Javascript using JQuery.